# Subclass of UINavigationBar - Setting translucent to YES not working

Tags: uinavigationbar, subclassing

Not sure if this is the correct approach but subclassing a UINavigationBar and setting it's translucent to YES doesn't seem to work.

In my implementation file:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    self.translucent = YES;
}
```

I was able to override it within a view controller, however, i find myself repeating code and would like to move the implementation in the custom class.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution if anyone needs it. Set self.translucent to YES on init:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.translucent = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

}
```